# How much jumps a normal accuracy graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

trained a model on 4 classes and tracked the results with TensorBoard. My Graph is looking like this:

[image: graph]

Greenline: val accuracy

Redline: train accuracy

You see that my val acc graph is jumping pretty much. Is this normal?

Comment: We need more information. The reason could be anything. It could be your dataset, code, loss function, network architecture, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is normal.

Heres whats happening.

1. The contour of loss function will have ups and downs. It is different for test and train but not significant.
2. When your train loss reaches minima, your accuracy will be relatively higher. This does not necessarily mean that your test loss **has to be** at a minima. When they differ significantly, overfitting occurs.
3. When the test loss is at a minima but train loss is not, your test accuracy will be higher than train. This is called underfit.
4. Fluctuations from the ideal path is normal. That is why tensorboard provides you the option to smoothen the edges. Use that option well and you can understand whether the model is performing well or not.

**Note** Overfitting/underfitting is not decided by a single observation. If the path of both losses deviate with increasing epochs, then we come to the conclusion about the performance of the model

Comment: Generally 5% and above of a difference is considered to conclude over/under fit. Depends on what you are working on

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for the validation accuracy to "jump" around especially in the initial epochs. Generally the jumps usually get smaller as the number of epochs increase. It is better to concentrate on the behavior of the validation loss since this is what you want to minimize. A smaller learning rate can often help to reduce the fluctuations.